# Adding a static page to squarespace (developer)

Tags: html, squarespace

I currently have a Squarespace site which is a bit old but still functional. It's going to be a while before I do the new site for it, however, I want to add a new page to the Squarespace site that is a static HTML page that functions as a mini preview to the new site.

I have made a separate site just for now and everything is ready to go up on the live account (that's paid for). The dev site I just did everything on the site. region file, however, the layout of the live site is a bit different since it's using a template.

I followed their docs to [this page on adding static pages...](https://developers.squarespace.com/static-pages/)

It says to add a folder called pages and 2 files, in my test I made barry.page and barry.page.conf

barry.page is a boilerplate HTML page for testing and barry.conf looks like:

```
{
    "title" : "Barry",
    "description" : "barry desc"
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is all I need to do however I cannot find the page when I run the site either locally or on Squarespace. localhost:9000/barry returns a 404.

How can I find this site, it would be a major pain if I had to host the site elsewhere and redirect from Squarespace because their docs aren't written well!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've pushed your changes to the server (and assuming you meant `barry.page.conf` not `barry.conf`), perhaps you've not set the URL for the page as desired using the "settings" icon to the right of the page in your "Not Linked" section (while in the back-end editing ["config"] area of your Squarespace website).

[image]

[image]

That should at least get the page to show up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're here in the future, Squarespace 7.1 does not offer the ability to create static pages as in Squarespace 7.0. You can see the version you're on by signing into your site dashboard > Help > scroll down to the bottom.