# Can we manually define all the HTML for one page of a Squarespace site, and use their UI for the other pages?

Tags: html, squarespace

I have a single complete HTML file which describes a webpage, and I would like to use this as the homepage for a Squarespace site. I would then like to design the other pages of the site as normal with the Squarespace editor UI, and have links to these pages from the homepage.

Does anyone know if it this can be done, and we can edit the HTML of a blank page from scratch in SqSp? I am aware of [Code Blocks](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167), but I can only seem to add a code block within an existing template.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you asked Squarespace support? What did they say?

Comment: Here is a related post that may contain helpful information on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612316/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For templates using Squarespace 7.0 (as opposed to 7.1 which at time of writing is the version that powers the templates currently promoted on Squarespace's website), this can be accomplished only by [enabling Developer Mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start) and then making use of either [static pages](https://developers.squarespace.com/static-pages) or a custom [.region file](https://developers.squarespace.com/layouts-regions), or both. This is something I do frequently.

As a disclaimer, I would not recommend enabling dev. mode on a live site or a site you have heavily invested time into unless you are experienced with dev. mode or are a very experienced developer in general. That is because there are consequences to enabling developer mode.

Besides the method described above, there are two other alternatives:

1. Use JavaScript to rewrite the page, which of course has its own drawbacks.
2. Use CSS to hide everything but the main body of the page, then use a code block in the body, pasting your code in there. Depending on your HTML, that might not work properly.

Comment: Thanks. I like the sound of the Static Pages option, but am currently using a 7.1 template. Is it possible to use a template 7.0 still? Do you know why they removed the Developer Mode?

Comment: To use 7.0, you'd need to start a new website. Most pros I know are still using 7.0 templates for many sites, so doing so is quite common. You can find a list of many of the 7.0 templates here: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206796007#toc-template-guides . To start a site from a 7.0, simply visit one of the demo sites and click on the prompt in the lower-right to create a site using that template. To get to a demo site, type the name of the template (lower-case) plus `-demo.squarespace.com` in your browser address bar. Most people start at brine-demo.squarespace.com .

Comment: Thanks for your help!